# Cannot find row in .META. for Table

Tags: hadoop, hbase, thrift, thrift-protocol

I am using Hbase 0.94.1 with Hadoop 1.2.1 and using Thrift API to access tables stored in Hbase from my C# application. I am able to connect to Server but while going to perform any operation from client it gives following error in CLI-log:

```
14/03/11 12:18:53 WARN client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Encountered problems when prefetch META table:
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.TableNotFoundException: Cannot find row in .META. for table: tblAssetsView, row=t\x00\x00\x00b\x00\x00\x00l\x00\x00\x00A\x00\x00\x00s\x00\x00\x00s\x00\x00\x00e\x00\x00\x00t\x00\x00\x00s\x00\x00\x00V\x00\x00\x00i\x00\x00\x00e\x00\x00\x00w\x00\x00\x00,,99999999999999
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.MetaScanner.metaScan(MetaScanner.java:151)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.prefetchRegionCache(HConnectionManager.java:1059)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegionInMeta(HConnectionManager.java:1121)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(HConnectionManager.java:1001)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(HConnectionManager.java:958)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.finishSetup(HTable.java:251)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.<init>(HTable.java:155)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.thrift.ThriftServerRunner$HBaseHandler.getTable(ThriftServerRunner.java:458)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.thrift.ThriftServerRunner$HBaseHandler.getTable(ThriftServerRunner.java:464)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.thrift.ThriftServerRunner$HBaseHandler.getRowWithColumnsTs(ThriftServerRunner.java:766)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.thrift.ThriftServerRunner$HBaseHandler.getRow(ThriftServerRunner.java:739)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.thrift.HbaseHandlerMetricsProxy.invoke(HbaseHandlerMetricsProxy.java:65)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy6.getRow(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.thrift.generated.Hbase$Processor$getRow.getResult(Hbase.java:3906)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.thrift.generated.Hbase$Processor$getRow.getResult(Hbase.java:3894)
    at org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction.process(ProcessFunction.java:32)
    at org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor.process(TBaseProcessor.java:34)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.thrift.TBoundedThreadPoolServer$ClientConnnection.run(TBoundedThreadPoolServer.java:287)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
 14/03/11 12:18:53 WARN thrift.ThriftServerRunner$HBaseHandler: tblAssetsView
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.TableNotFoundException: tblAssetsView
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegionInMeta(HConnectionManager.java:1139)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(HConnectionManager.java:1001)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(HConnectionManager.java:958)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.finishSetup(HTable.java:251)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.<init>(HTable.java:155)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.thrift.ThriftServerRunner$HBaseHandler.getTable(ThriftServerRunner.java:458)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.thrift.ThriftServerRunner$HBaseHandler.getTable(ThriftServerRunner.java:464)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.thrift.ThriftServerRunner$HBaseHandler.getRowWithColumnsTs(ThriftServerRunner.java:766)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.thrift.ThriftServerRunner$HBaseHandler.getRow(ThriftServerRunner.java:739)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.thrift.HbaseHandlerMetricsProxy.invoke(HbaseHandlerMetricsProxy.java:65)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy6.getRow(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.thrift.generated.Hbase$Processor$getRow.getResult(Hbase.java:3906)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.thrift.generated.Hbase$Processor$getRow.getResult(Hbase.java:3894)
    at org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction.process(ProcessFunction.java:32)
    at org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor.process(TBaseProcessor.java:34)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.thrift.TBoundedThreadPoolServer$ClientConnnection.run(TBoundedThreadPoolServer.java:287)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

But I can access my table from Hbase Shell with all shell operations. 
I am totally stuck here, please devise some methods to overcome this issue.

Comment: I'm having similar problem when connecting with a Java client, I would be interested to know how did you solve this?

Comment: In my case I was using Thrift API in C# client, are you also using Thrift API in Java Client?

Comment: no but thrift is based on the hbase api and the exception is occurred at the level of the hbase api

Comment: I agree for that, If so you have to check for the table existence in Zookeeper server and try to delete the row if it is there.

Answer (score 0):

I have encounter this error
finally turned out I used wrong configuration files,I have two cluster，I used another cluster's configuration files.
Maybe your configuration have 
some problem